# I have one dataset having 30 instances. I have to choose 4 random distinct variables for each 10 10 instances

Tags: matlab

4 distinct data from 1-10 instances, another 4 from 11-20instances, another 4 from 21-30 instances.

I have used 
randperm(n,k) function

k->4 %no of distinct data

n %range from 1-nth instance to choose randomly

So,in 1st iteration n = 10. So that it will take randomly from 1st-10th instances

n For 2nd time must be within range of 11-20

So, I tried giving n = 20, but later I thought. It will search from 1-20 where as I wanted 11-20.

So, data which are not selected from 1st iteration(1-10) can come in this iteration
Eg if 2,4,6,7 choosen in 1st iteration. And in 2nd iteration it will choose between 1-20 except 2,4,6,7. So, 3rd,8th instances can come. Where as I want it should be within 11-20

In the end it will store, 4 index
rnd = randperm(n,k)
xr1 = rnd(1) %1st index value stored in rnd

c is the loop in a counter starts from 0

So, for second iteration c= 1

What I have done for minor adjustment
After getting data

xr1= rnd(1)+c*10

So, exactly I am not getting random values
If in 1st round it select 2,4,6,7
So, in round I am choosing 12,14,16,17

It's not a permanent fix

Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would edit your post in order to improve readability. But then I realized I cannot even understand what you are saying or asking. Please, improve the writting

Comment: I am trying my best. Let me correct again

Comment: Is it ok now @EuGENE ?

Comment: Show code, and format it as code

Answer (score 1):

You know that `randperm(10,4)` gives you 4 unique integers in range 1-10. To get 4 unique integers in the range 11-20, simply add 10. For range 21-30 add 20:

```
randperm(10,4)       % 4 random unique integers in range 1-10
randperm(10,4) + 10  % 4 random unique integers in range 11-20   
randperm(10,4) + 20  % 4 random unique integers in range 21-30
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better approach than randperm here.
If you want random integers between 2 limits check this out:

desired_number = round (10 + (20 - 10) .*rand(1,1));

this code will give you a random integer between 10 and 20 you can change 10 and 20 with variables and use a for or while loop

In short:
Formula:
desired_number = round (a + (b - a) .*rand(1,1));
where "a" is lower limit "b" is upper limit.
I hope this answers your questions, if not please feel free to ask.

Comment: Instead of generating doubles and then rounding them to integers it's better to generate integers form the start with `randi(4,1)`, since OP needs 4 numbers. `randi` allows you to specify the range, so you can rewrite your solution as `desired_number = randi([a b],4,1)`. The downside is, that `randi` doesn't necessarily gives distinct numbers, so then you would need to include a check for that.

Comment: True, I personally use this formula to generate real numbers (doubles), but in case of integers it is better to stick with randperm.